# How do I split my data set between training and testing sets while keeping the ratio of the target variable in both sets?

Tags: r, machine-learning, training-data

I have a data set which I intend to split between a `training set` and `testing set` for a `machine learning` analysis using `R`.

Assuming my data set (called `MyDataset`) has a ratio of Yes (60%) and No (40%) based on the target variable (called `Leaver`), how can I ensure that my split will maintain that ratio in both the training set and the testing set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is stratified splitting of your dataset. You can do this with the `createDataPartition` from the caret package. Just make sure your `Leaver` variable is set as a factor.

See a code example below.

```
library(caret)
data(GermanCredit)

prop.table(table(GermanCredit$Class))
 Bad Good 
 0.3  0.7 
index <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = 0.6, list = FALSE)

# train
prop.table(table(GermanCredit$Class[index]))
 Bad Good 
 0.3  0.7 
#test
prop.table(table(GermanCredit$Class[-index]))
 Bad Good 
 0.3  0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Package:

```
GermanCredit$id<-1:dim(GermanCredit)[1]

bad_id<-sample(GermanCredit$id[GermanCredit$Class=="Bad"],0.6*.3*300)
good_id<-sample(GermanCredit$id[GermanCredit$Class=="Good"],0.6*.7*300)

train_index<-sample(c(bad_id,good_id))
#train set
prop.table(table(GermanCredit$Class[train_index]))
Bad Good 
0.3  0.7 

#test
prop.table(table(GermanCredit$Class[-train_index]))
Bad Good 
0.3  0.7
```